# truck will not start

Tags: ford, starting, f-350

2000 F350 Diesel will not turn over.  Replaced Fender mounted solenoid and batteries and it still just clicks. Had the starter tested and it tested good.  Still just clicks, could it be the starter solenoid is too weak to work when installed?

Comment: Was the motor running prior to the current problem? Make sure the fender mounted solenoid has a solid ground, wirebrush the mounting surface prior to remounting it.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that a battery connection or corrosion concern would be the cause.  I also would like to point out that diesels do not have distributor caps or spark plugs.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning the engine over manually- say a socket and bar on the crankshaft pulley nut. If the engine will rotate then you have got to go through the battery/battery cables, both live and power for continuity/starter.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Allan on checking the battery cables. Specifically check out the connections at the terminal and the connection from the battery to the starter. If the starter and battery are good the likely culprit is a weak connection.

Comment: I'd also check the ground cable where it attaches to the frame. Every time I've had an issue where the engine wouldn't crank, it was the battery or the ground cable.